# does the scheduler on a flatMap() observable affect the scheduler on the outer observable?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

This might seem like a bit of a silly question and I've done a few tests to see how it works in practice, but I'd like to see it confirmed and if possible I'd like to know why in terms of the Observable contract and its implementation because it feels like a nasty hole in my understanding of the rules of Rx. Plus if you can tell me where to look for this then it'll help me answer these questions myself in future.

If I use the following Observable:

```
Observable.range(0, 3)
          .observeOn(schedulerA)
          .flatMap(i -> Observable.just(i)
                                  .observeOn(schedulerB)
                                  .map(j -> -j))
          .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println(String.format("Got %d", i)))
          .subscribe()
```

Then will the operator `.doOnNext(i -> System.out.println(String.format("Got %d", i)))` be executed on `schedulerA` or `schedulerB` and is there a formal or specification based reason as to why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no guarantee on which scheduler `doOnNext` will run. It could be either one of them in a probabilistic fashion.

The reason for this is that the `flatMap` operator uses an advanced fast-path & work stealing algorithm that could be triggered by either thread and will perform some of the tasks of the other thread as well.

With the trivial inner `Observable` finishing up quickly, it may be possible `schedulerA` is still handling its subscription and detects that the value from the inner source is available, thus emitting it on the same `schedulerA` thread. Other times, `schedulerA` finishes handling the inner `Observable` before that produces an item. In that case, `schedulerB` will trigger an emission inside the `flatMap`.

Generally, when you uncertain which thread will handler your `doOnNext`, always apply an `observeOn` with the desired scheduler just before it.

Comment: Oh jeez, so I wasn't imagining it when I remembered seeing it occurring on both. That's reassuring. Thanks!